# Environment PATH variable affecting Relative File Path(s)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I had this console application. Now i have added Environment variable PATH to its setup so that it can be executed from any location through Console. Strangely, the same application is breaking after this change.

Installation directory contains, BIN and CONFIG folder. Exe is placed inside BIN folder.

I have this line of code,

```
WriteToFile(@"..\Config\Settings.xml")
```

The path used to write to a file Settings.xml inside Config folder inside the INSTALLATION DIRECTORY. However, now it tries to write to settings.xml inside Config folder at EXECUTION PATH.

So, if i execute my app from console as c:/users/guest/app.exe, it would try to interpret path relative to this location AND NOT relative to installation directory for the application.

Any help, suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the path of the executing assembly then add to it the folder and file name:

```
string pathOfExecutingAssembly = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
string settingsPath = pathOfExecutingAssembly + "\\..\\Config\\Settings.xml"
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try getting the Executing Application's Path and append it before the path where you want to save

Comment: just clicked post answer, your answer came on top :)

Answer (score 0):

Path starting from \ means: start from the root directory on the current drive. \Config\Settings.xml executed from any C subdirectory gives: C:\Config\Settings.xml.

BTW, do you post exact code? It should be WriteToFile(@"\Config\Settings.xml") or WriteToFile("\Config\Settings.xml")

In any case, you need to decide, whether you want to search configuration file using absolute path, or path relative to current directory/installation directory/executable directory. The code, installation package and execution command should be changed accordingly.

Comment: Really sorry for not having posted exact code. But my main concern was to firstly confirm, can such a drastic side-effect be caused by only adding Environment PATH variable to setup.

Comment: This is not PATH, this is current directory that can change your program behavior, since you use relative path. After changing the PATH variable you can now run your application from the console window, without cd to application executable directory.